# How to Select / Highlight text box content on first click only

Tags: javascript, jquery, scripting

Please does anyone know the script that can help me highligh the content of a textfield on the first click

on the second click the selection / highligh should be cleared from the text box leavingg the insertion point.

Thank You in ADvance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script selects the text on the first click, but after every consecutive click the textarea will behave like a textarea always does. When the text area loses its focus due to the blur event and you click on it again, the text will be selected again.

[Live Demo on JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lzhc7/)

```
(function () {
    var area = document.querySelector('#txt'),
        clicked = false;

    area.addEventListener('click', function () {
        if (!clicked) {
            area.select();
            clicked = true;
        }
    });

    area.addEventListener('blur', function () {
        clicked = false;
    });    
})()
```

Because of [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener) and [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelector) the example is not fully cross browser compatible.

Answer (score 1):

```js
    function SelectText(sender) {
        document.getElementById(sender.id).focus();
        document.getElementById(sender.id).select();
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="tbTest" value="Test" onclick="SelectText(this)" />
```

Comment: This code continues to select the text on succeeding clicks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/4Hkhx/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input').click(function(){
    $(this).select();
  });
});
```

Comment: Well this will select the text on every click, won't it?

Comment: Try the demo. I dont' know why but it is what he wants

Comment: you're indeed right. sorry. Do you know why this works? I'd expect it to be selected on every click

Comment: Another click(any where on the document) will make browser clear the document's current selection, I guess :D

Comment: Hum, maybe. Curious if this is consistent behavior across browsers.

Comment: this script does not work.. it only highligh the text box content on the first click.. but does not clear the highligh or selection on the other clicks

Comment: it does in Chrome, which browser are you using?